# Android - SharedPreferences

Tags: android

Não está dando certo meu sharedPreferences.

```
public static final String PREF_NAME = "TelaApresentacaoActivityPreferences";

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);

       mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
       mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
       mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
       mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(newViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    });

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
}

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.commit();

}

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();

}
```

No meu AndroidManifest.xml, coloco trecho de código dentro

```
 android:onHistory="true"
```

Comment: O que não está dando certo?

Comment: quando fecho aplicação e abro ela novamente ela aparece a ActivityApresentacao.

Comment: Explique o que está a tentar fazer.

Comment: No meu app tenho uma Screen Slide, quero que execute apenas uma vez, quando usuário for fechar a aplicação ele não esteja visível para usuário novamente, assim como o login também.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toda vez que a Activity é destruída, os dados são removidos:

```
   @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();

}
```

comente esta parte :

```
 editor.clear();
```

Para verificar se seu app já rodou, faça o seguinte:

```
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);

               mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
               mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
               mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
               mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(newViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            });

            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

boolean jaRodou = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("JaRodou", false);

if(jaRodou){
// se entrar aqui é pq já executou o codigo algiuma vez
}else{

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("JaRodou", true);
    editor.commit();
}
        }
```

Comment: não deu certo, minha activity ainda continua visível.

Comment: Falta voce salvar algo..  Vou atualizar a resposta

Comment: ainda continua visível, porem ele entrou no if, no else ele não entrou

Comment: então é true, certo?  ali vc faz o que tenque fazer, no seu caso esconder sua tela!

Comment: tendi. tentar aqui.